# Rails use the same endpoint instead of two new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I need to display `purchased` Book in one page and `planned_purchase` Book in other page. The view will be the same so my question is - do I need to create new controller method and routes to display both or can I use e.g. `Index` and somehow display two different values depending on request?

current code below:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :fetch_conversation

  def index
    @planned = Book.planned_purchase
    @purchased = Book.purchased
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  scope :purchased, -> { where(purchased: true) }
  scope :planned_purchase, -> { where(purchased: false) }
end
```

Comment: Are you using any pagination or you have 2 different buttons or `<a href>` for these 2 pages to access? can you paste your view level codes?

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand: you can do this thing using a single controller `GET` action.

So, you've this `BooksController` and `index` action, which I assume can be accessible via `books_path`.

You can modify the `index` method, as follows to accept a new parameter by which you can filter the books:

```rb
def index
  case params[:filter]
  when 'purchased'
    @records = Book.purchased
  when 'planned_purchase'
    @records = Book.planned_purchase
  else
    @records = Book.all
  end
end
```

Now, you have a view page `books/index.html.erb` for this `index` action. Let's break this into 2 separate partials.

In `books/index.html.erb`:

```rb
<% if params[:filter] == 'purchased' %>
  <%= render "partial_for_parchased" %>
<% elsif params[:filter] == 'planned_purchase' %>
  <%= render "partial_for_planned_parchased" %>
<% end %>
```

Inside those partials you can modify the view based on the category.

Now, to get those two different page, you need to define 2 separate urls:

1. `<%= link_to 'Purchased', books_path(filter: 'purchased') %>`
2. `<%= link_to 'Planned Purchased', books_path(filter: 'planned_purchase') %>`

As your, `def index`, is a GET method and not depending on the strong parameters, so you don't need to add `filter` in your `params.required(:book).permit(...)`

Hope I covered all the areas!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer should be pretty simple and straight.
You can just pass a parameter to the index method and filter records inside it and return them.

```
def index
  case params[:filter]
  when 'purchased'
    @records = Book.purchased
  when 'planned_purchase'
    @records = Book.planned_purchase
  else
    # get all records or throw an error
  end
```

Comment: I don't get it. So what should the controller and view files look like to have two pages - `link_to 'Purchased'` and `link_to 'Planned to purchase'`

Comment: You can use like `link_to 'Purchased', books_path(filter: 'purchased')`

Comment: If my books_params are `params.required(:book).permit(#some other params ..., :filter)` how to avoid an error: `param is missing or the value is empty: book` ?

Comment: You should check params[:book].present? before requiring.

Comment: Ok, I know I could use just ` params[:filter]` but how to require `:book` inside of link_to ? What is next step if I use `params[:book].present?` it just checks if :book exists, I have to tell him what's next.